# Implementation non-generic IEnumerable from mother class

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I would like to ask the experts on a problem I am facing. On a bottom-up approach, I have a class StandardAccount, initialized with a couple of simple properties, one of which is enum (and a GUID which is setup automatically upon instantiation, like

```
public class StandardAccount
{
    private Guid _id;
    private string _accName;
    private AccountType _accType;
    private double _balance = 0;
    public enum AccountType
    {
        [Description("Asset")]
        AT,
        [Description("Liability")]
        LY,
        [Description("Profit")]
        PT,
        [Description("Loss")]
        LS
    }

    public StandardAccount(string name, AccountType type)
    {
        this._id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this._accName = name;
        this._accType = type;
        this.Balance = 0;
    }
    public double Balance { get => _balance; set => _balance = value; }
}
```

A Book class, must have one or more lists of those StandardAccounts and an Accounting class must have many Books. I prepare my Book class in a way to be searchable (will have many lists of StandardAccount and I need to be able to find a StandardAccount by GUID later on in those lists). I setup my Book class as follows:

```
public class Book
{
    private string _bookName;
    private short _bookNum;
    private Guid _bookId;

    public List<StandardAccount> Accounts { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<StandardAccount> GetEnumerator() => Accounts.GetEnumerator();

    //compile time err: containing type does not implement interface 'IEnumerable'
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => Accounts.GetEnumerator();
    
    //updated
    public void Add(string name, StandardAccount.AccountType type) => Accounts.Add(new StandardAccount(name, type));

    public Book(Guid? id, short BookNumber, string BookName, IEnumerable<StandardAccount> Account)
    {
        this._bookId = id ?? Guid.NewGuid();
        this._bookNum = BookNumber;
        this._bookName = BookName;
        this.Accounts = new List<StandardAccount>();
    }
    public Guid id { get => _bookId; set => _bookId = value; }
}
```

I have these two errors that doesn't let me go forward and I don't understand them (as I am trying to implement the enumerator in the 'mother' Book class and not in StandardAccount)
Could someone please help and advise?

Note:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

I am trying to do this:

```
//this works fine
StandardAccount stdAccount = new StandardAccount("account one", StandardAccount.AccountType.AT);
//this workds fine
stdAccount.Balance = 123;

//but.. cannot add the account to my book
//ERROR - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
myAccounting.Book.Accounts.Add(stdAccount);
```

Comment: why do you need that functionality? if you need to iterate over accounts, do this: `foreach (var account in book.Accounts)`

Comment: A book isn't a collection of authors. it *has* authors. Having a `GetEnumerator` that returns an unrelated entity is going to confuse everyone, even the author (you) after a while

Comment: Why are you trying to implement `IEnumerable` in the first place? Your `List` already has those features.

Comment: For the other error, you need to add a new instance of `Account`, not just two properties. But again, that method isn't needed because the `List` property already has it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Kalimera! Thank you for the note, I might have chosen the wrong implementation. I previously tried with IList and seemed not appropriate (obviously I might be wrong). Do you have an example on how I could search an account (from within the Book class) based on a GUID id?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov Thank you very much for taking a look in it, I was thinking implementing an I-feature to be more straight forward. Your approach is also correct..

Comment: @DavidG Thank you very much, I think you are right; you mean, at the Add to go with
... => Accounts.Add(new StandardAccount(name, type));

Comment: @Nick what everyone means is that treating `Book` as a container of `Author` objects is *very* unusual and almost always wrong. What if you need to add tags and keywords to the book? Or chapters? Why would iterating a book return the authors instead of the chapters?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Minor point, but you keep saying "Author" instead of "Account" :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I do understand the concern, thank you! Actually, the book will be one (if multi-company, then another book will be opened exceptionally) and in real life contains only two lists, Accounts and Reports. I am trying to build the Accounts.. In reality, each book is for 1 year, and when next year comes, all accounts will be copied to a new book (setting balance 0). That's the (oversimplified) real-life basis.. But I stuck in being able to search an Account by a GUID (I see GUIDs in transactions and I don't know to which account and in which book they belong...)

Comment: So you have an accounting problem and the book is actually an accounting period or a ledger. The ledger contains transactions against specific accounts, not the accounts themselves.

Comment: @DavidG duuh, a book has authors, not accounts. So I kept seeing accounts. If the word Ledger was used, I wouldn't even think about authors - I have the misfortune of querying ERP tables on occasion.

Comment: BTW use `decimal` for counting money, as `double` introduces round off errors of the form `x=1.429999999999999997` instead of `x=1.43` for example.

Comment: @JAlex, correct, I have it in mind - this is just a skeleton.. Thank you for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

```
//compile time err: containing type does not implement interface 'IEnumerable'
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => Accounts.GetEnumerator();
```

This means you are using an [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). However, the book class does not implement the IEnumerable interface, so this causes an error.

Solution would be to either implement the interface

```
public class Book : IEnumerable
```

Or remove the explicit part. Note that this require a namechange since you already have a method with the same signature.

```
public IEnumerator GetNonGenericEnumerator() => Accounts.GetEnumerator();
```

However as mentioned in the comments. This is probably not a good approach to the problem. I.e. you should use composition instead of inheritance, i.e. "a book *has a* list of accounts", not "a book *is a* list of accounts".

It is not obvious from the question exactly what you want to search for and what result you expect. If you want to search for a book what has an account with a specific id you could use:

```
myBooks.Where(b => b.Accounts.Any(a => a.Id == idToSearchFor));
```

but you would need to make the Id public. If you want the actual accounts returned instead you could use:

```
myBooks.SelectMany(b => b.Accounts).Where(a => a.Id == idToSearchFor);
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much! You are right, I clarify: I try to do `StandardAccount stdAccount = new StandardAccount("account1", StandardAccount.AccountType.AT);` and then simply  `Book.Accounts.Add(stdAccount);` And yes, exactly as you wrote, and others as well, a Book _has_ (not is) many accounts. I try to search, list by list in a book, for an account with a specific (known in advance) GUID id.